# Extract number form a currency $100

Tags: php

How to extract the only number from a `currency $100?`

This is not working `preg_match_all('/(\d+.?\d+)/',$price,$matches);`
matches[1] is empty

I don't have any other possibilities to extract the number from a string

Answer (score 6):

Best is to use [`NumberFormatter::parseCurrency`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php):

```
<?php
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$amount = '$100';
echo $formatter->parseCurrency($amount, $curr);
```

[Demo here](https://3v4l.org/lkPF4)

This will also allow characters that can usually belong in a money amount (floating points and commas), and convert it to a proper float value.

Comment: Oddly it looks like its removed in >7.3.0 as your demo shows, 10y in the business I've never seen that class :/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It's back in 7.3.0 rc1 upwards, it's weird that it "disappeared" during its alpha version but those were actually older.

Comment: Plus 1 for mentioning a less known class.

Comment: This method should be preferred over the regex examples, especially if the currency string can be more complicated than "$100", such as "$1,234,567.223".

Comment: @AaronSt.Clair that is nowhere near a complicated string to parse with regex. https://3v4l.org/DcVoh the problem is that OP has not given us anything to work with. But you are correct about more complex strings, except that numberformatter fails and not the regex. https://3v4l.org/ejmfj

Answer (score 2):

You don't need preg_match_all, a normal preg_match is all that is needed.
And your pattern suggests there is multiple digits?

This works, but not sure what your string looks like. You didn't include that in your question.
It matches only digits.

```
$price = "$100";
preg_match('/([\d\.]+)/',$price,$match); 
var_dump($match); //100
```

https://3v4l.org/BE0Nj

Comment: The dot does not need escaping inside of a character class and when matching the whole pattern, there is no benefit to using a capture group.  You are misrepresenting the output -- it is a two-element array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "$100";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

[Reference](https://gist.github.com/lerua83/7448987)

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
                 [0] => 100 
              )
     )

echo $matches[0][0];
```

Output:  `100`